# Version code not found in aar file's AndroidManifest.xml after upgrading agp

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, aar

I have a library which I distribute with aar files. In previous builds, `AndroidManifest.xml` included versionCode and versionName, but after upgrading agp and gradle, they are not found in the manifest. Is it a breaking change in agp? The previous agp version was `3.6.3` and now I've upgraded to `4.2.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google having a version for libraries (present in the manifest file or in code) does not make sense for libraries in Android. Only applications have an android version.

For info versionName and versionCode have been removed from AGP 7.0.0.
I guess in AGP 4.2.2 you can set versionName and versionCode but they are not generated in the Manifest file of aar.

Comment: Then how can I know which version of a library an app is using, if aar files are distributed locally (and not through maven)? Is there any other way to specify the version of a library?

Comment: You can eventually put the version name directly in the name of the .aar file like below

`libraryVariants.all {
            
   outputs.all {
                packageLibraryProvider {
                    archiveFileName.set("LibraryName-${buildType.name}-v$versionName.aar")
                }
            }
        }`